# How to draw rectangles using a loop?

Tags: java, swing, object, for-loop, colors

I need to create a loop which draws rectangles in a vertical line with alternating color (e.g. black, white, black, white). Can anyone tell me how this is done?

I have tried numerous ways but can't seem to get the loop to work, thanks.

```
for (int x = 0; x>10;x++) {
    int y= 180;
    graph2D.drawRect(170, y, 20, 50);
    y = y + 45;
}
```

This is what I have, it won't draw the rectangles for some reason and I cant get it to alternate colors.

Comment: We probably need to see more code since it isn't working. Are you able to draw a single rectangle, without the loop?

Comment: To start, you are re-initializing `y` each time you enter the loop so the squares are drawing on top of each other. Try moving `int y = 180;` before the loop and see what you get. From there you can work on colors and the rest

Comment: `String color = x%2 == 0 ? "black" : "white"`. Something like that with color changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a few issues here.

Your `for loop` will not perform any iterations, as your condition is `x > 10` instead of `x < 10`.

Change the first line from:

```
for (int x = 0; x>10;x++){
```

To:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
```

Also, you reset `y` to 180 every iteration, so once your loop does start, all of the rectangles will be drawn on top of each other. Declare `y` outside of the loop, or use `x` to calculate the rectangles position.

Either like this:

```
int y = 180;
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    graph2D.drawRect(170, y, 20, 50);
    y = y + 45;
}
```

Or like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    graph2D.drawRect(170, (x * 45) + 180, 20, 50);
}
```

The above math `(x * 45) + 180` is a super simple way of saying that the first rectangle will be at `(x * 45) + 180 = 0 + 180 = 180`, the second will be at `(x * 45) + 180 = 45 + 180 = 225` and so on and so on.

To change the color of the rectangles, you'll need to make a list or array of `Colors`, and use a different `Color` from the list, in each iteration.

```
//Make the list
Color[] colors = {Color.black, Color.blue, Color.cyan, Color.darkGray,
                  Color.green, Color.lightGray, Color.magenta, Color.magenta,
                  Color.orange, Color.pink, Color.red, Color.white, Color.yellow};

//Draw each rectangle
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {

    //Change the color
    g.setColor(colors[x]);

    //Draw the rectangle
    graph2D.drawRect(170, (x * 45) + 180, 20, 50);
}
```

Of course if you want the colors to be random, you can look into using the `Random` class, and generating a random number between 0 and the length of your `colors` array. Also note that I use `x` as an index for the `colors` array, and if your loop increments x to be higher than the number of colors in the array, you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I also assumed you named your instance of `Graphics` as `g`, since it is done that way most of the time.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, how would I make it so that the rectangles are filled in the loop instead of just the outlines changing colour? I didnt think of using an array for it so thanks for that

Comment: No problem, to make the rectangles filled in simple use the method `fillRect` rather than `drawRect`. It takes the same parameters as `drawRect` so all you have to do is change the name.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use the `y` variable instead of `x` that you are looping though?

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics graph2D) {
    for (int y=0; y<10; y++) {
        int height = 50;
        if (y%2==0) {
            graph2D.setColor(Color.white);
        } else {
            graph2D.setColor(Color.black);
        }
        graph2D.fillRect(170, 180 + y*height, 20, 50);
    }
}
```

Also mind the difference while drawing a rectangle:

- `.drawRect(..)` draws the border of a rectangle.
- `.fillRect(..)` draws the rectangle itself.

---

In case you want to switch between `black` and `white` color, change the color with every loop. Every even number `y%2 == 0` of loop will have the one color, otherwise the second one (also mentioned in the code above):

```
if (y%2==0) {
    graph2D.setColor(Color.white);
} else {
    graph2D.setColor(Color.black);
}
```

Comment: `static final int` may be slightly better than simply `int` - it is a compile-time constant, better not leave it to the JVM to recognize that.

Comment: @SándorMátyásMárton Where are you talking about?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt It was a side remark about `height`, the loop variable is not a compile time constant of course :)

Comment: @SándorMátyásMárton Oh of course, I don't know why I didn't immediately realize what you meant.